# Is $x^2 +2y$ surjective for $f: R \times R \rightarrow R$?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

Is $x^2 +2y$ surjective for $f: R \times R \rightarrow R$?

I think it is, because $x$ and $y$ can be any real number, so it seems rational to conclude that using any combination of rational numbers you should be able to create all other rational numbers.

However, I am wondering if there is a more mathematical way to prove this?

Comment: Is the function $2y$ surjective from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Also, I do not get your concern about rational numbers, as that does not seem to be in the problem statement.

Comment: Perhaps it is $f:\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: it would surjective even in the case $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 3):

Choose $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(0,r/2) \mapsto r$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix any $w,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $w-y\in\mathbb{R}$, so suppose $z=w-y$. Of course $y/2\in\mathbb{R}$, so let $s=y/2$. Then $z+2s=w$. But once again, $\sqrt{z}\in\mathbb{R}$ so say $x=\sqrt{z}$ Then we have that $$x^2+2s=w$$ i.e. $f:(x,s)\mapsto w$ .Since $w$ was arbitrary, we can complete this same process with any element in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You lost me when you started your proof "Fix any $w,y \in \mathbb{R}$."  I would not expect a proof that a real-valued function is surjective to start that way.  A start of "Fix $z \in \mathbb{R}$" would be more meaningful to me. Anyway I'm not sure what you are trying to prove, or if you are ambiguating your answer to avoid answering fully.

Comment: @Micheal We would like to show that given any $w\in\mathbb{R}$, that there exist $x,s\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,s)=x^2+2s=w$. So perharps I should have said fix $w\in\mathbb{R}$, and for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, ... and gone down the same path. Make sense?

Comment: I edited my comment as you were typing yours, so I would be more clear.  You got my meaning, your above comment makes sense.